# Unable to run a HelloWorld Scala program on Ubuntu

Tags: scala

I have my very first Scala program, which is as simple as:

```
object HelloWorld{
    def main(args: Array[String]){
        println("Hello world!")
    }
}
```

I then try to compile it like so:

```
$ scalac HelloWorld.scala
```

And it compiles without any error messages. When however I try to run it like so:

```
$ scala HelloWorld
```

I get an error message:

> No such file or class on classpath: HelloWorld

To implement this, I followed [this](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/166) tutorial and to solve the emerged error, I followed [this](https://ramugvs.wordpress.com/2014/09/05/scala-no-such-file-or-class-on-classpath/) suggestion. However,

```
$ scala objects.HelloWorld
```

also does not work. I know many people will now start heavily voting down my question and asking questions - have you ever tried to read some books on it (Yes, I did. I've read Horstman book for beginners, but it does not contain any information on compiling programs under Ubuntu). Still, I hope someone could help.

Comment: this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191489/scala-problem-how-to-run-a-program-that-is-in-a-package suggests to try to add current directory to classpath. Although I did exacly what you listed and got `Hello world!` on my stdout on ubuntu.

Comment: Works for me too. Maybe you might try: `scala -cp . HelloWorld`

Comment: @Madoc. When I do `scala -cp . HelloWorld`, I see that it compiles and then immidiately runs. Altough, it seems to work, I think, it is not what I need in the long run.

Comment: @Jacobian, for the long run you should use build tool like sbt, gradle or maven.

Comment: @roterl. Thanks, I will check all that.

Comment: @Jacobian Wow, now that is highly unusual. The `scala` command should never compile! You must be mistaken. How do you _see_ that the compilation process takes place? `-cp .` simply tells the `scala` command to include the current directory in the classpath, nothing more. It should be like this by default, but somehow, it seems your configuration might be messed up, and the current directory is not part of your classpath. But, as @roterl noted, you should definitely use a tool like SBT on the long run.

Comment: @Jacobian Argh, actually I was totally wrong there. `scala` is the Scala Repl of course. And that obviously compiles the code, of course. In order to run a compiled Scala program, you should of course use the `java` command. Sorry, I was mislead there. So you should actually type: `java HelloWorld`, just like with a Java program. However, it might be necessary to include the Scala library JAR in the classpath.

Comment: @Madoc. It was just my thought. I beleived that `-cp` stands for `compile`. And besides, when I did it I saw the same messages, as I had seen before when doing `scalac ...`

Comment: @Jacobian Yes, sorry. Just try the `java` command, as I noted in my previous comment. And don't forget to include the scala library JAR in the Java classpath, as I mentioned. Under the hood, Scala compiles to the same bytecode as Java, so you don't need a separate command to run it.

Comment: @Madoc. Thank! Using `java` command helped to do the trick. You can make an answer from this, so that I could accept it.

Comment: @Jacobian Good point, thanks. I've made an answer that contains all of this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This was a comment before, and I rephrased it to a response.)

You've done everything right, except for the last step: Use the `java` command instead of the `scala` command.

`scala` is the Scala REPL. No separate run command is required for Scala code, because it compiles to regular Java bytecode.

So try: `java HelloWorld`

For more complex programs that make use of the Scala library however, you need to include the Scala runtime library in the classpath. So, on the long run, it is beneficiary to use a tool like SBT, as pointed out by @roterl in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

The answer saying that the `scala` command is just for the REPL is incorrect. You can see from the man page entry for `scala` (http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs-2.10.2/manual/html/scala.html) that it is intended to be used in the same way as the `java` command with the added flexibility that it will run the REPL, scripts, or compiled applications.

As some of the comments have indicated, this is almost certainly a path issue, which means that it requires more information to diagnose. One thing you can check is whether the `scalac` command produced a `.class` file in your current directory. If that is in the directory where you are running `scala` then the comments about needing `.` in your classpath are almost certainly correct.