# No such file or class on classpath: Hello.scala

Tags: scala, class

I am a scala beginner and have created a simple "Hello world" scala script, as Hello.scala. When I run it from console : `$ scala hello.scala`

It gives me the error : `No such file or class on classpath: Hello.scala`

How do I get to know my scala classpath and therefore place the Hello.scala file on classpath ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to run a HelloWorld Scala program on Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33065292/unable-to-run-a-helloworld-scala-program-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly go to Directory where `Hello.scala` is placed.

Then open terminal there 
type `scalac Hello.scala` this will compile the `Hello.scala` file.

Then type `scala Hello` this will run you file i am assuming that class name that contain main method has the name `Hello`.

Hope This Work !

Answer (score 1):

The Source file name and Object name (contains main) can be named different. I think users are passing scala source file name (without filename extension) by mistake instead of Object name to "scala" binary.

Here hello.scala is a source file compiled but you have to pass Object name defined inside your source file to run the actual program.

```
$ scalac <source-file.scala>
$ scala <Object-defined-in-scala-souce-file>
```

Answer (score 0):

The current directory is typically not in the classpath by default.
Try this:

```
scala -cp . Hello
```

My current working dir is /home/dmitry/scala/testsimplejar/tmp.

For me, this works: `scala -cp "/home/dmitry/scala/testsimplejar/tmp" Hello`

This doesn't work: `scala -cp "/home/dmitry/scala/testsimplejar/tmp/*" Hello`